# Make bibliography not part of previous chapter

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

I'm writing my thesis and I have a problem with references:

The references span across two pages. On the top of the second page there is a header (that appears on every page where a new chapter does not begin). The header informs a reader about the current chapter he/she is reading. But in the references it says "Conclusion", which is my last chapter. I would like this not to appear in the references (or say "References"). There are some other chapters after References, that I would like to keep their headers (`\appendix`).

This is the code to create references (bibtex):

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{thesisrefs}
```

This makes the headers:

```
\def\ps@thesisheadings{%
\def\chaptermark##1{%
\markright{%
\ifnum\c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\thechapter.\ %
\fi ##1}}
\let\@oddfoot\@empty
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\def\@oddhead{\vbox{\hbox to \textwidth{%
\hfil{\sc\rightmark}}\vskip 4pt\hrule}}
\if@twoside
 \def\@evenhead{\vbox{\hbox to \textwidth{%
 {\sc\rightmark}\hfil}\vskip 4pt\hrule}}
\else
 \let\@evenhead\@oddhead
\fi
\def\@oddfoot{\hfil\PageFont\thepage}
\if@twoside
 \def\@evenfoot{\PageFont\thepage\hfil}%
\else
 \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
\fi
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Please indicate how the References section/chapter is generated: via BibTeX (or biblatex) or entirely manually?

Comment: [Here](http://leteckaposta.cz/510467850) are the files you'll probably need to compile an example...I'm unable to make it a better way

Comment: References section is generated using BibTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently your bibliography command doesn't update the running heads. Judging from your code, you just need to call `\chaptermark{References}` (manually or automatically) when the bibliography starts.

Presumably this doesn't happen because your bibliography is a section, not a chapter. If you don't like the idea of calling `\chaptermark` for a section, just call `\markright` directly.

Comment: The `\markright` did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. You are now supposed to close the question by "accepting" my answer.